# About an error with the command "gitbook pdf"

Tags: pdf, gitbook

I met a problem.
I run the command "gitbook pdf", and it show me this Error:

EbookError: Error during ebook generation: 1% Converting input to HTML...
InputFormatPlugin: HTML Input running
on /tmp/tmp-72206AoHgIzetV6D/SUMMARY.html
Language not specified
Creator not specified
Building file list...
Normalizing filename cases
Rewriting HTML links
34% Running transforms on ebook...
Merging user specified metadata...
Detecting structure...
Detected chapter: Introduction
Detected chapter: CH1
Detected chapter: CH2
Detected chapter: Item 1
Auto generated TOC with 4 entries.
Flattening CSS and remapping font sizes...
Failed to parse CSS selector: u'h|button::-moz-focus-inner'
Failed to parse CSS selector: u'h|input::-moz-focus-inner'
Failed to parse CSS selector: u'h|input[type=search]::-webkit-search-cancel-button'
Failed to parse CSS selector: u'h|input[type=search]::-webkit-search-decoration'
Source base font size is 12.00000pt
Removing fake margins...
Cleaning up manifest...
Trimming unused files from manifest...
Creating PDF Output...
67% Running PDF Output plugin
Traceback (most recent call last):
`File "/usr/bin/ebook-convert", line 20, in``<br>
sys.exit(main())`
`File "/usr/lib/calibre/calibre/ebooks/conversion/cli.py", line 359, in main<br>
plumber.run()`
`File "/usr/lib/calibre/calibre/ebooks/conversion/plumber.py", line 1189, in run
self.opts, self.log)`
`File "/usr/lib/calibre/calibre/ebooks/conversion/plugins/pdf_output.py", line 123, in convert`
`must_use_qt()`
`File "/usr/lib/calibre/calibre/gui2/__init__.py", line 1041, in must_use_qt
raise RuntimeError('X server required. If you are running on a'
RuntimeError: X server required. If you are running on a headless machine, use xvfb`

what's the error mean?

Comment: "RuntimeError: X server required. If you are running on a headless machine, use xvfb" what exactly don't you understand? you could try `xhost +local:` as the owner of the desktop and `export DISPLAY=:0.0` in the shell where the script is run if you do have X windows